# groupadd hangs while /etc/group.lock does not exist only works with -g param

Tags: 16.04, users, groups

I have a problem with adding group on ubuntu 16.04.
I tried to add group using groupadd , but the tasks hangs until i kill it.
before running it again i have to remove /etc/group.lock.
and then when i try it it hangs again

the line that hangs:

```
sudo groupadd testt
```

i have managed to make it work when adding **-g param**

```
sudo groupadd -g 10000 testt
```

i am on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS, with windows AD

what could be the reason?

Comment: Don't use AD but perhaps it needs an explicit GID addition with the `-g` option!

Comment: i have used it for few years with allot of linux system, this is something new.  never occurred before